# get value of ddl, txtbox, calendar used in user control on main page using findcontrol in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I want to do a task in which i want that using findControl during the use of webusercontrol on web form to get value of webusercontrol on main page I mean, I've created a webusercontrol and have used on web form. In webusercontrol.ascx page i use a textbox, calendar, and dropdownlist. Now I want to get value(which i choose from txtbox, ddl etc) should be display on main page. I mean, I want to use a button on default.aspx page and in a variable want to store value of txtbox, calendar etc. and using a FindControl want to get these values on main page. How I can do this plz help me by code plz I'm new in programing.

```
This is the code of ascx page

 <%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="CalendarUserControl" %>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="Beige" >
    </asp:Calendar> 
    <br/>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlthings" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem> Apple</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem> Banana</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem> Mango</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem> Grapes</asp:ListItem> 
    </asp:DropDownList>
default.aspx page

<div>
    <uc1:CalendarUserControl ID="CalendarUserControl1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Button" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define properties in your user control, that will return values of controls you want. For example

```
public partial class CalendarUserControl: UserControl
{
   // this is code-behind of your user control
   public string Data
   {
      get {return txtData.Text;}
   }

   public DateTime CalendarDate
   {
      get {return Calendar1.SelectedDate;}
   }

   // same approach for drop down list ddlthings
}
```

Then in your aspx page, just read those values, for example in your `btn_Click` event handler

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var textBoxValue = CalendarUserControl1.Data;
   var calendarValue = CalendarUserControl1.CalendarDate;
   //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i did it, just write these lines in default.cs

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox myLabel = (TextBox)CalendarUserControl1.FindControl("txtData");
        string x = myLabel.Text.ToString();
        Calendar c = (Calendar)CalendarUserControl1.FindControl("Calendar1");
        string date = c.SelectedDate.ToString();
        DropDownList b = (DropDownList)CalendarUserControl1.FindControl("ddlthings");
        string ddl = b.SelectedValue;
        Label1.Text = "Your text is: " + x + "<br />"+ " Your Selected Date is: " + date + "<br />"+ " Your Selected Item is: " + ddl;
    }
```